# Setting string for config (Bukkit)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So currently I am making a plugin to remake mineplex features, and I got stuck when I got to bans, because I was trying to make it so that when you ban someone it puts a string in config with their name which you said in args, & then the string would have a value of "banned".. However when I do the command it says the message, gives me an internal error, and doesn't set thing string, anyone know why? (The error is on getConfig.set)

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ban")) {
        Player p = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
        if (args.length == 0) {

            sender.sendMessage("&9GWEN> &7Specify a player to ban");
        } else {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',
                    "&9GWEN> &7" + args[0] + " &7has been banned. I am always watching."));
            getConfig().set(p.getName(), "banned");
            if(!(p == null)) {
                p.kickPlayer("You have been banned by a mod");
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: So I redid the code, here is the new code.. No errors but it doesnt change the config

````
            Player p = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage("&9GWEN> &7Specify a player to ban");
            } else {
                if(!(p == null)) {
                    p.kickPlayer("You have been banned by a mod");
                }
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',
                        "&9GWEN> &7" + args[0] + " &7has been banned. I am always watching."));
                this.getConfig().set(args[0], "banned");
                saveDefaultConfig();
            }
        }```
````

Comment: Hint: when you compiled with warnings, did you get one about `if(!(p == null)) {` always being true?

Comment: When I compiled I got no warnings

Comment: You have warnings turned off. Turn them on and recompile.

Comment: I dont. btw I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is 
`saveConfig()`
instead of 
`saveDefaultConfig()`

Spigot JavaDocs say this regarding `saveDefaultConfig()`
https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/plugin/Plugin.html#saveDefaultConfig--

> Saves the raw contents of the default config.yml file to the location retrievable by getConfig().
>   This should fail silently if the config.yml already exists.